# How to import a react file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to both JavaScript and React.js and I'm having trouble with imports.

I have the following index.js file:

```
var Main = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <Main/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

the following pub.js file:

```
export default class Pub extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>test</div> ;
    }
};
```

The pub.js file and the index.js file are contained in the same folder -> /scripts. I also have following index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Application</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly fine, i.e. loads a page that reads 'test'

But if I simply import the Pub class(without even using it) as below, the app breaks and nothing is rendered on the screen.

```
import Pub from './pub'

var Main = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <Main/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Additionally, in case the error is caused by an unused import, I've also tried the following :

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Pub/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

If anyone could shed some light on the issue, or even better, point me towards a good tool for syntax checking React.js code I'd appreciate it.

Comment: imports don't work in the browser, you need something to import for you like webpack / browserify / rollup

Comment: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app is a pretty good get up and running base if you don't want to get into learning webpack

Comment: Also - https://reactforbeginners.com/ is a really good resource to learn the basics (and more advanced stuff later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using webpack for building/transpiling/serving my code.

i've tried your sample and it works in such setup:

i created Pub.jsx component and exported in such way:

```
import React from 'react';

class Pub extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ</div>;
    }
}

export default Pub;
```

then i imported Pub component to another component in same directory and it is rendered correctly:

```
import React from 'react';

import Pub from './Pub';

class ExplorableList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Pub />);
    }
}

export default ExplorableList;
```

Rendered result in browser: https://www.screencast.com/t/Ojwrq3KNE

My folder structure: https://www.screencast.com/t/9Mi8LLdnv

Check if it works for you (if not, provide exact error you are getting)